# iterating over a doubly linked list from device

Tags: c++, cuda

I need to create a doubly linked list on a cuda device.
I have the host code:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int my_index;
    static int count;
    static int index;
    static Foo* first;
    static Foo* last;
    Foo* next;
    Foo* prev;

    Foo(); //adds object to list
    ~Foo(); //deletes object from list
}

Foo* Foo::first = 0;
Foo* Foo::last = 0;
int Foo::count = 0;
int Foo::index = 0;
```

when i want to iterate through it:

```
for (Foo* pr = Foo::first; pr; pr = pr->next)
{
    //do something
}
```

My first problem is:
there are several **other classes** that **inherit** from `Foo`
and they have differrent sizes, so how can I:

- either copy all
  created classes of type `Foo` and all derived classes to the device
- or even better, completely store the whole linked list from `Foo` on the device

I dont have to access the data from `Foo` on the host,
I need it **only** on the device.

My second problem:
I have multiple CUDA devices (3 CUDA capable graphic cards)
how could i access the device doubly linked list on both devices?

- peer-to-peer copy?
- something else?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? The performance of linked list traversal in a CUDA thread will be disappointing.

Comment: Given that it's a linked list, it doesn't seem like the different sizes of the classes should be problem. Are you having problems actually iterating the list of objects (e.g. the list doesn't contain everything that you expect it to), or is the problem that you're not sure how to do what you want (apparently copying the objects somehow) as you are iterating through them?

Comment: on the host, the iteration works pefect. my only problem is to copy the whole list to the device.

Comment: @Schnizel1337: The whole point is that you cannot copy a linked list of host pointers to the device. Pointers are not portable and there is no automagic deep copy functionality in the API. The only choice is to construct the list out of one or more device memory allocations. You can do this either in device or host code. But you cannot *copy* a linked list you created in host memory to the device.

Comment: @talonmies Yes, I've expected to hear something like that..
I have now added a function that creates a copy of the whole list and transferes it to the device.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with CUDA, but it sounds you need to transform each object into some form so that it can be transferred to the device, and the problem is that the objects are different sizes and have different contents. If so, you should be able to solve the problem with a virtual function that transforms each object into a form that can be transferred according to its type. For example, if you were transferring data as binary using a `void *` buffer, it might look like:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    // ... Everything else ...

    virtual void *add_transfer_data(void *buffer)
    {
        // Copy whatever makes sense for a Foo object into the buffer.
        memcpy(buffer, [something], n);

        return reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(buffer) + n;
    }
};

class Bar: public Foo
{
public:
    // ... Everything else ...

    virtual void *add_transfer_data(void *buffer)
    {
        // First, take care of the Foo part of the object.
        buffer = Foo::add_transfer_data(buffer, buffer_size);

        // Now copy whatever else a Bar object needs into the buffer.
        memcpy(buffer, [something], m);

        return reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(buffer) + m;
    }
};

void transfer_data(void *buffer)
{
    void *next_location = buffer;
    for (Foo* pr = Foo::first; pr; pr = pr->next)
    {
        next_location = pr->add_transfer_data(next_location);
    }

    // Send the contents of buffer to the device somehow.
}
```

Of course, your versions of `add_transfer_data` might be very different depending on the details of how the transfer works and what the objects look like. There might be nothing to write for just a plain Foo object, for example. Hopefully, though, this illustrates the central idea.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know anything about CUDA, so there is likely a better answer.

If your problem is determining the size of an instance of `Foo`, then why not give the class a virtual `size` method?

```
// In Foo:
virtual size_t size() const;

// In class T, a derivation of Foo:
size_t size() const override { return sizeof(T); }
```